# Tokenizing a string, errors with recognizing char

Tags: c++

I'm having a bit of trouble with a school assignment for C++.  The specific problem I'm having involves reading lines from a file that contain a series of between 5 and 6 grades.  The grades for each student appear together in a single line following the student's name and id number.  The challenge here is that the grades can have a variable number of spaces between them, and that if there are only 5 grades present, an error message needs to be generated to screen but the program is to continue running and average the 5 grades.  Example of input: 23 46     68   85       98

I got the student name and id easily, but the string of digits is giving me problems.  My plan was to getline and then tokenize the string and assign each token to a cell in an array.  This works fine for 6 grades, but when only 5 grades are present it is assigning garbage to the sixth cell.

Here is the snippet of code that concerns this section:

```
fin.getline(gradeList, 200);

grade = strtok (gradeList, " ");


while (grade != '\0')
{         
      gradeArr[cycler] = atoi(grade);
      grade = strtok(NULL, " ");
      cycler++;
}
```

I tried doing an isdigit check on each token before converting it to an int, and writing a 0 in for any token that failed the isdigit check, but that didn't work at all.  It seems like it is pulling the name from the next line when only 5 grades are present and then when it atoi's it, it changes it to a huge number.

I thought that when the program did getline, it would only grab the line until it saw the endline terminator.  Is this not what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `strtol` or `strtod`, it gives you back a pointer to the end of what you just processed, so you can continue from there.  No tokenization necessary :)

<strike>But it sounds like your problem is that you're reading the wrong line.  Print out the `gradeList` variable before you start parsing.</strike>

You should end up with something like this:

```
fin.getline(grade_text, 200);
const char* grade = grade_text;
const char* next_grade;

double grade_sum = 0;
for( int grade_count = 0; grades[grade_count] = strtol(grade, &next_grade, 10), next_grade > grade; ++grade_count )
    grade_sum += grades[grade_count];
double mean_grade = grade_sum / grade_count;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you still need to skip over whitespaces?

Comment: @KerrekSB: All handled for you. "The expected form of the (initial portion of the) string is optional leading white space as recognized by isspace(3), an optional plus ('+') or minus sign ('-') and then either (i) a decimal number, or (ii) a hexadecimal number, or (iii) an infinity, or (iv) a NAN (not-a-number)."

Comment: Thanks, that's neat. Yes, that'd be a lot faster than iostreams, and it's a good alternative to consider, even in C++.

Comment: I checked to see if it was reading the wrong line and when I cout the string, it is showing the correct numbers with 5 or with 6 grades.  When I tokenize it though, it works perfectly with 6 grades, but with 5 it give me something like 1999398543 when i cout gradeArr[5].

Comment: @LuckyMeadows: Well, you're counting the number of valid grades you had, using `cycler`.  So don't use any that aren't valid.  BTW, `gradeArr[6]` is the 7th value, and going to be garbage any which way.

Comment: Ya i meant gradeArr[5], I saw that 2 mins after I put up. My mistake.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ya, I think I can follow it, but I'm going to try and separate some of it out because I need to get the data in some form where I can bubble sort it with a separate function then use another function to calculate average of the 5 highest grades, thus dropping the 6th (maybe a numeric grade or a blank).  Finally, we have to use another function to assign a letter grade based on the average and another function tell the total number of a's, b's, c's etc.. in the class.

Answer (score 3):

Scrap the C nonsense and use real C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// ...

std::vector<int> grades;

std::string line;

while (std::getline(fin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int grade;

    while (iss >> grade)
    {
        grades.push_back(grade);
    }
}
```

Here's a somewhat more compact and elegant method, using istream-iterators and back-inserters:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
// other headers as before

std::vector<int> grades;

for (std::string line; std::getline(fin, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(grades));
}
```

The point is that formatted token extraction (`>>`) from streams does already precisely what you want to, and it subsumes both tokenizing and parsing into integers.

The `istream_iterator` encapsulates the token extraction and allows you to treat a stream as if it were already a sequence of parsed tokens. The `copy` algorithm then simply copies this sequence into a vector, inserting it at the end of the container.

Comment: Unfortunately we are prohibited from using string library.  cstring is fine, just no string.